# How to get the soft keyboard type (QWERTY, (X)T9, etc.)?

Tags: android, events, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

In a series of `EditText` views, the cursor should automatically jump to the next view, after the 5th character is typed.

I do this like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  int twTreshold = 4;

  etKey1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_levels_key1);
  // ...
  etKeyX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_levels_keyX);

  etKey1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if (s.length() > twTreshold)
        etKey2.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
      if (currentText.length() > twTreshold)
      etKey2.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
      int after) {
    }
  });
}
```

**The problem now is:**
The user might use a T9 or similar keyboard. There, in order to input the letter "B", the button "ABC" on the keyboard has to be pressed. An "A" is concatenated to the EditText's text, the event `onTextChanged()` is fired. Too early! The user still has to press the button "ABC" another time to replace the "A" with a desired "B".

My idea was to get the keyboard type and, if it's of the type as mentioned here, just not to switch focus automatically.

Has someone maybe an idea how to retrieve the keyboard type?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I'm dealing with the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is one. There are thousands of different combinations to get a user's thoughts into characters (not to mention a semantic element that a word is) at the level our software can deal with. Imagine gesture based keyboards at where you swipe around, others where you tap a button multiple times to get the desired value, as both software and hardware keyboards, also a variety of keyboard apps available out there…
With a loose definition like that of what a keyboard actually is, no further classification will be possible.